# What lifting is best for discus training?

Tags: strength, training

After learning about the difference between bodybuilder training versus powerlifter training, I want to know about how to strength train for the discus throw.

Is high weight and low reps best for me to develop dynamic strength and maintain speed in the discus circle?

Answer (score 2):

For your specific question, from what I remember from college, your weight training is going to be dependent on what part of the season you are in, and is going to be a progressive thing. So, for your off season, you will be doing sets in the 8-10 rep range, and as your season progresses, so will the weight and the reps will start dropping down.

For other considerations, you will probably want to add serious core work, plyometrics, agility. Strength is a key part of the discus, but balance through the spin, being able to translate that spin into the motion with a coordinated toss, etc. are going to matter just as much as how strong you are. I would highly recommend finding a coach that can teach you all aspects of the training and techniques.

Here's a few references I found for exercise programs. The one from brianmac outlines more of what I was talking about, the other one strictly addresses weights.

[Brian Mac](http://www.brianmac.co.uk/discus/plan.htm)

[Coaches Education](http://www.coacheseducation.com/strengthtraining/bill-pandleton-dec-00.htm)

Comment: Also check out Tudor Bompa's “Periodization Training for Sports" http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0736055592/ref=mp_bxgy_p_dp_y  You are going to lean towards power lifts but you must have a periodized training plan to prepare you for successful competition.

Comment: will 8-10 reps during off season help me to develope dynamic strengh of upper body ??

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Dan John's work. He's a former discus thrower and has a lot to say on the subject. Much of what he recommends is essentially powerlifting with an upper-body and power focus.

Recurring elements of his discus advice include deadlifts, power cleans, and overhead squats.

His short book "A Contrarian Approach to the Discus Throw" covers much of his thought on the issue. His [opinion on the basics](http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/sports_body_training_performance_interviews/old_school_soldier), however, are well known:

> What most people need to do is squat, press, deadlift, clean, snatch, jerk, dip and chin. You know the drill. "Dan, how many chins?" someone will ask. Well, how many can you do? "I dunno. I've never done one!" Hmmm, as an expert in all things, let's try this: let's see how many you can do!

That said, my totally uneducated opinion (I've never even held a discus) I think high weight for five reps or less would almost certainly be best. Lowering the weights in order to do power exercises like cleans would be OK.

Comment: where i find Dan John's workout or any other pro discus thrower waight training schedule of off season??